# Java threading objects

Tags: java, multithreading

I've created an object of arrays with a size of 1000, they are all threaded so that means 1000 threads are added. Each object holds a socket and 9 more global variables. The whole object consists of 1000 lines of code.

I'm looking for ways to make the program efficient because it lags. CPU use is at 100% everytime I start the program.

I understand that I'm going to have to change the way the program works, but I can't find a good way. Can anyone explain how to achieve this?

Comment: I think the phrases "1000 threads" and "CPU use is at 100%" go together pretty well. You might want to rethink your design a bit...

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what your threads actually do - are the tasks primarily using CPU or other resources? For CPU intensive tasks, the best strategy is to run as many threads as you have cores, or a few more. For threads which are blocking a lot on e.g. reading files, waiting for the net etc. you can have many more threads than CPUs.

It also depends on how many cores the system has. Obviously the answer is very different for a single processor machine than for a 128-way multiprocessor. The above rules of thumb can give you some estimates, but it is best to make experiments yourself based on these, to figure out the ideal number of threads for your specific setup.

Moreover, since Java5, it is always advisable to use e.g. a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) instead of creating your threads manually. This makes your app both more robust and more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

1/ use thread pool

2/ use futures

Comment: funny. futures do help a lot.
most of the times, it is possible to replace multiple threads by sequences of the actions to be performed periodically and here the futures and proper executor are coming.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider refactor you usage of threads.

1000 Threads normally makes no sense on a normal machine/server although your problem seems to be I/O-heavy. You should consider the number of cpu-threads that are available.

A possible solution would be to use a dispatcher that passes the handling (and possible responding) to a request on the socket into a queue of a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, 1000 threads are just too many (at least on 8core/8GB RAM machines). A common symptom is context switching slashing, where your OS is just busy jumping from thread to thread while doing little useful work (and a lot of memory is wasted etc.).

If you have to *maintain* 1000 sockets, you probably have to go for NIO. Easier way out would be closing/opening sockets every time (whether you can do this dependents on the characteristics of your work.).

The way you solve this many thread problem is to use a thread pool, as others note. Instead of extending Thread, code a Runnable instead. This is easier said than done though because you have to maintain state if you need conversation. This commonly involves a `ConcurrentMap`. I personally tend to put a Handler (which implements Runnable) on this map that should run when the counter party returns a response (the response contains a key everytime). In this case you'd be closing the socket every time. If you use NIO, it's more like coding with Threads in the sense you don't need to identify the counterparty like this, but it has its own complexity.